# Allow replying-to dynamic local-part of address sent by sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have user in my system who can send emails through my API. The API uses SendGrid to send the emails with their username as the sender + reply-to address.

```
user_1@mydomain.com
user_2@mydomain.com
user_3@mydomain.com
```

What I would like to do is allow people to reply to these emails but I'm unsure how to do this.

Obviously if I try to reply as is - I get an error saying the email couldn't be delivered.

Is there something to do with SendGrid which can handle previously unseen addresses `@mydomain.com` or do I need to do something to set them up initially in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use [incoming web-hooks](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Inbound_Parse_Webhook/setting_up_the_inbound_parse_webhook.html).